# How to fix mypy error when using click's pass_context

Tags: python, mypy

I am using [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com) to build a command line application. I am using [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org) for type checking.

However, passing a context to a function using `@pass_context` works as expected, but mypy fails with the error:

```
error: Argument 1 to "print_or_exit" has incompatible type "str"; expected "Context"
```

and I don't get why. Below is the MWE to reproduce this mypy error:

```py
import click
from typing import Optional

@click.pass_context
def print_or_exit(ctx: click.Context, some_txt: Optional[str] = "") -> None:
    if ctx.params.get("exit_", False):
        exit(1)
    print(some_txt)

@click.command(context_settings=dict(help_option_names=["-h", "--help"]))
@click.option("--exit","-e", "exit_", is_flag=True, help="exit")
@click.pass_context
def main(ctx: click.Context, exit_: bool) -> None:
    print_or_exit("bla")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Running the script using the argument `-e`, then the script exists, without printing to the terminal; when omitting `-e`, the script prints to the terminal, therefore everything works as expected.

So, why does mypy fail?

Comment: Did `ctx` arg int `print_or_exit` is an `str` or `click.Context` ?

Comment: Does your mypy have access to a stub library for the `click` module?  If not, is has no way of knowing that `@click.passcontext` modifies the following function by changing its arguments.

Comment: @FrankYellin yes, i'm using click version > 8 which has builtin stubs as far as I understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked to the [sources of click](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/main/src/click/decorators.py#L20), `decorators.py`

```
F = t.TypeVar("F", bound=t.Callable[..., t.Any])
FC = t.TypeVar("FC", t.Callable[..., t.Any], Command)


def pass_context(f: F) -> F:
    """Marks a callback as wanting to receive the current context
    object as first argument.
    """

    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):  # type: ignore
        return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)

    return update_wrapper(t.cast(F, new_func), f)
```

So, function `pass_context` return same type (`-> F`) , that receives in arguments (`f: F`). So, mypy expects, that you pass two arguments in `print_or_exit`.

I think the best solution would pass `ctx` explicitly wherever you can. The benefit of this -- you can easily mock `ctx` in your test for `print_or_exit` function. So, I suggest this code:

```
import click
from typing import Optional

def print_or_exit(ctx: click.Context, some_txt: Optional[str] = "") -> None:
    if ctx.params.get("exit_", False):
        exit(1)
    print(some_txt)

@click.command(context_settings=dict(help_option_names=["-h", "--help"]))
@click.option("--exit","-e", "exit_", is_flag=True, help="exit")
@click.pass_context
def main(ctx: click.Context, exit_: bool) -> None:
    print_or_exit(ctx, "bla")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It works as expected and passes mypy

Comment: This looks like a bug in the annotations. `pass_context` should not be annotated as returning the same type it takes.

Comment: The ideal fix would be to use [`typing.ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) (and get the backported ParamSpec from [`typing_extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) for older Python versions), but without ParamSpec, the best option is probably just `Any`.

Comment: @Eugenij I accept this as an answer, as this is currently the only option (altougth I don't  like it).

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks for the information. How exactly should it be annotated? Did you create a Pull Request in the project on GitHub?

Comment: @user69453: It should look pretty much like the `with_lock` example decorator in the [`typing.Concatenate` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Concatenate), but with a click.Context instead of a lock.

Comment: The feature is super new, though, and [mypy doesn't even have proper support for it yet](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11833). If you try using the "correct" annotations, currently, [mypy throws an error](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=ca4a516032b0aa07f8a9626ea3aaf77b) because it doesn't understand Concatenate yet. In the absence of proper mypy support, Any may be the way to go for now.